# Error in Code: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for TEST/ANKUR

Tags: java, mysql

```
package javaapplication1;
import java.sql.*;
public class JavaApplication1{
  public static void main(String[] args) {
  System.out.println("MySQL Connect Example.");
  Connection conn = null;
  String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST/ANKUR1";
  String dbName = "jdbctutorial";
  String driver = "com.mysql.jdbc.Driver";
  String userName = "root"; 
  String password = "root";
  try {
  Class.forName(driver).newInstance();
  conn = DriverManager.getConnection("TEST1/ANKUR","root","school");
  System.out.println("Connected to the database");
  conn.close();
  System.out.println("Disconnected from database");
  } catch (Exception e) {
      System.out.println(e);
  }
  }
}
```

I had installed MySQL 5.5 on my machine and I copied Java-connector.jar file in the required folders. My Database is test1 and table is ankur. Please see I was using this code to just to check the connectivity with my NetBeans 7. Any suggestions?

Comment: I know there are some problems but I want to know why this error is showing up?

Comment: Have you added the mysql jar reference in your project?

Answer (score 0):

The URL you actually use in `getConnection(...)` is wrong.  You are not supposed to put in just the name of the table you want to work with.  You need to have a complete URL so the JDBC system knows that it should use the mysql driver and where the mysql driver needs to connect to.

Recheck the example you copied from, and see where they use the "url" variable.

Answer (score 0):

The [JDBC URL format](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html) when using the MySQL Connector/J driver is:

> jdbc:mysql://[host][,failoverhost...][:port]/[database][?propertyName1][=propertyValue1][&propertyName2][=propertyValue2]...

Therefore, the actual URL to be used in your case ought to be (if the database is installed on your local machine with name TEST and listening on the default MySQL port of 3306):

> jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST

and not the below.

> TEST/ANKUR1

Remember that JDBC URLs are used by the `DriverManager` class to determine which driver ought to be used to connect to the database, and where the database is located. One does not connect to tables in JDBC; instead, one connects to a database (or a schema) and then issues SELECT queries against tables. Your method therefore, would look like:

```
conn = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/TEST","root","school");
System.out.println("Connected to the database");
PreparedStatement pStmt = conn.prepareStatement("SELECT * FROM ANKUR");
ResultSet rs = pStmt.executeQuery();
...
//Process the contents of the ResultSet
...
rs.close();
pStmt.close();
conn.close();
```

It should be noted that it a good practice to close the `ResultSet`, `PreparedStatement` and `Connection` objects in a finally block.